# Conditional formatting VBA different cell as condition

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add conditional formatting to a cell, but the value for the condition is another cell.

The condition should go into this cell: `Cells(x, cellcounter)`

`If Cells(x, cellcounter) > 0 then Cells(y, cellcounter) color RGB(153, 199, 112)`

This is what I have come up with, but it gives me an error. What would be the correct syntax?

```
Cells(cell_quote_paid, cellcounter).FormatConditions.Add(Cells(cell_pending, cellcounter), xlGreater, "=0").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 199, 112)
```

Thx for the help!

Comment: have you tried macro-recorder? It will provide you full solution and support.

Comment: yes I have. This is my last resort :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2010 there's no need for VBA.

1. place Excel cursor in cell (y, cellcounter) and click [Conditional Formatting] - [New Rule...] from the Styles section of the Home ribbon
2. click "**Use a formula to determine which cells to format**"
3. place cursor in field "Format values where this formula is true"
4. click in cell (x, cell counter) ... it will show e.g. =$A$1 (i.e. the reference of the cell delivering your condition)
5. add ">0" to formula and select the format

You can apply the same rule to multiple cells using [Conditional Formatting] - [Manage Rules...], so all cells will turn red if condition cell goes from 0 to 1.

To do the same in VBA, use the following methods and properties:

```
{target range}.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A$1>0"
{target range}.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
{target range}.FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(153, 199, 112)
{target range}.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```